# nvm doesn't work/install on Manjaro linux

Tags: linux, nvm, manjaro

I need nvm to downgrade my node version. So I install it with pamac:
`pamac install nvm`

`Preparing... Warning: nvm-0.39.5-1 is up to date -- skipping Nothing to do. Transaction successfully finished.`

Then I try to use it and:
`bash: nvm: command not found`

Also tried `nvm -v` or `nvm --version` and doesn't find the command. I've tried to intall it by curl with:
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash` from the github repo.

I found [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/what-is-the-proper-way-to-install-node-js-with-nvm/101720/4) on Manjaro's forum but I'm not quite sure if it's me who don't understand or if it's other problem. I'm on Manjaro 23.0.4. Thank you

Tried the command, doesn't work. Tried installed from github, doesn't work. Read a manjaro forum, doesn't undertand it. Expect other solution/aproach beside unistall manjaro and move to debian or arch

Comment: On Linux, after running the install script, if you get nvm: command not found or see no feedback from your terminal after you type command -v nvm, simply close your current terminal, open a new terminal, and try verifying again. Alternatively, you can run the following commands for the different shells on the command line:

bash: source ~/.bashrc

zsh: source ~/.zshrc

ksh: . ~/.profile

These should pick up the nvm command. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official [doc](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux):

On Linux, after running the install script, if you get nvm: command not found or see no feedback from your terminal after you type command -v nvm, simply close your current terminal, open a new terminal, and try verifying again. Alternatively, you can run the following commands for the different shells on the command line: bash: source ~/.bashrc zsh: source ~/.zshrc ksh: . ~/.profile These should pick up the nvm command